# Using Terraform data resource kubernetes_all_namespaces during plan without the k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I'm trying to get the data resource **kubernetes_all_namespaces** from the k8s cluster and the result of the data will be used in the for_each of a resource. The data resource fails to retrieve anything and fails the build at PLAN stage. How to resolve a dependency like this? I've tried using depends_on but that hasn't worked too.

```
data "kubernetes_all_namespaces" "dataresource" {}
```

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "con-map" {
 for_each = toset(data.kubernetes_all_namespaces.dataresource.namespaces)
 ...
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error you get. I'm not sure I understand what you mean in the title with "without the k8s cluster". Are you saying you don't have a Kubernetes cluster? If so what are you expecting to happen here in that case?

Comment: the data sources are always executed first than the resources, so in this case I think you do not need any depends_on, my assumptions is that you have not set up the access to the cluster well, check the set up par https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/guides/getting-started to see if you missed something, or check the Kube config applying some kubectl commands confirm the access to the cluster